# Force a NULL or unknown type value to an integer in Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net, integer, vb.net-2010

I want a fail-safe way to force an int, in my current situation i'm declaring a zero early but it's been nagging me. I like to be direct, fast, and clean. I can presume some responses already, but after using this method in javascript i found that it was quite efficient when i needed an integer value. I know javascript is very forgiving, i am looking to eventually write safe signal processing code for whatever industry so fast methods which will round off safely, and turn nulls and nothings to zeros rule.

To be clear again, I need a working replacement for

`Y = ~~(X)`

which i've used happily in JavaScript, but i can't do `~` Character in Visual basic. it's fine if there isn't i'm just wondering.

Comment: well, context is kind of abstract. the expected output is an integer. Input is Supposed to be integer, but i'm just learning this oop stuff. it's confusing.

Comment: its an object property. i guess that wasn't very clear in my post. sorry. I'm not good at asking questions, either. ha.

Comment: Ah, I see. The other way .. once again, tag to specific language. I think this time we got it :D

Comment: right, but i'm talking forcing "null" = 0 as an integer

Comment: What should happen if the value is `"1"`?

Comment: that's fine. i just don't like ctype i guess. I heard it takes memory and whatnot, sends object to memory locations three times or something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`int(x)` will work, and there's less typing (pun intended) than with cType.